# Integrating google+ api in iphone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata, google-plus

I am developing an application in which I have to give support for google + login also.i follow this link to download the latest version of google +(gdata)api and I integrated it in my project.When I run it it was showing 16 errors.I added json files.Now it is showing 2 errors of some redundant files.

Please suggest me how to solve this or any other way to integrate google + api.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library for using the Google Plus API from iOS and Mac is [google-api-objectivec-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).

It includes a sample Cocoa app using the Plus API, as well as the [gtm-oauth2](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/) library for signing in from iOS apps.

Comment: can you please help me in integrating it if you have done this before.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to include some frameworks! Or maybe you haven't set some paths the right way for the json files

Answer (score 1):

A complete guide and step by step objective c API integration can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue of integration of Google Api Client for Objective C.

I am not an expert but wrote a tutorial how I integrated it so someone may save time. It can be found [here](http://techxposed.blogspot.com/2012/09/google-objective-c-client-api-xcode.html)