# How to integrate Google+ API in iPhone?

Tags: ios, integration, google-plus

Is there Google API for iPhone out yet?
And if YES, how can I integrate within my application.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555268/integrating-google-api-in-iphone-project

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not a code writing service. You should make a best effort attempt to solve your problem yourself, then ask a question when you have a specific issue. See [ask] and [faq]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was already answered on SO, see [Is there already a Google+ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api).

Basically, go to http://developers.google.com/+/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am looking for some tutorial or steps to integrate Google Plus API

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to anonymously check out the latest Google SDK project source code for Objective C:

```
svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) includes support for the Google Plus API and other JSON APIs.  The project includes an [introduction](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction) to using the library.