# Login with google in iphone app

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any approach to login into the iphone app through Google credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932122/is-there-any-approach-to-login-into-the-iphone-app-through-google-credentials)

in My application i have three option for social login e.g. Facekbook,twitter and Google i have done with Facebook and twitter but not with google anybody can give me any link or solution for login with google in my app

thanks

Comment: Go to [this link](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/) as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817707/how-to-integrate-google-api-in-iphone. Hope any of the same be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use GData for objective-c

I have used it for Picassa integration, it works very well;

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction

Comment: see here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543582/how-to-use-gdata-in-iphone

Comment: you need to do a read-only checkout from google code, the commend is "svn checkout http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gdata-objectivec-client-read-only" see http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/checkout